# Show monotonicity of solution of Delayed Differential Equation with respect to a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

## Short Description of the General Question

Suppose we have some Delayed Differential Equation (DDE) which depends on a parameter $a$, $x_a'(t)=f(a,x_a(t),x_a(t-s))$ for some fixed $a$ and $s$. I would like to prove that $x_a(t)$ is increasing in $a$. I.e. if we have $a<b$ and $x_a'(t) = f(a,x_a(t),x_a(t-s))$ and $x_b'(t)=f(b,x_b(t),x_b(t-s))$ then $x_a(t) \leq x_b(t)$ for all $t$.

## Specific Scenario

Consider the following Delayed Differential Equation:
\begin{align*}
x_a(0) &= a\\
x_a'(t) &= - a (1 - x_a(t)^2) & t \leq 1\\
x_a'(t) &= -a(x_a(t-1)^2 - x_a(t)^2) & t > 1.
\end{align*}
I have found numerically that for all $a \in (0,1)$ we have:
$$
a \leq b \Rightarrow x_a(t) \leq x_b(t),
$$
but I am unable to prove this statement. I can solve the ODE in $[0,1]$ exactly, thus on this interval it is easily verified that $x_a(t) \leq x_b(t)$. I then use that solution to find a solution on $[1,2]$ and so on. But as $t$ grows large we can't find an exact solution anymore.

Comment: In general, x'$_a$ = f(a,b,c) = -a contradicts the desired conclusion.  Also, some boundary conditions for the x's needs to be set.

Comment: Yes of course this statement isn't true in general, but I am looking for some method to try and show that it is true (a method which at least works on the provided example)